# How to read a chrome html file from a folder in jupyter notebook using python

Tags: python, html, url, jupyter

I found this in another link but it did not work

```
fname = 'US7931083B2' (I tried the full path as well )

html_file = open(fname, 'r')
source_code = html_file.read() 
source_code
```

I am getting an error

> FileNotFoundError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         6 fname = 'US7931083B2'
>         7 
>   ----> 8 html_file = open(fname, 'r')
>         9 source_code = html_file.read()
>        10 source_code
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'US7931083B2'

Comment: I saved the file as html only in the jupyter notebook code folder.